# Pass AttributeSet as parameter in custom view constructor in AppWidget for android

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-appwidget

I need to pass AttributeSet as a parameter in custom View constructor. Here is the attribute that I need to pass:

> `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>   <resources>
>       <declare-styleable name="DonutChart">
>           <attr name="radiusDonut" format="dimension"/>
>           <attr name="donutTextSize" format="dimension"/>
>       </declare-styleable>
>   </resources>`

I need to do this with code, in order that I will add my custom view to RemoteView in my AppWidget. Does anyone has any idea how can I achive this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [XmlPullParser](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html) to get the attributes from your XML resource and then pass those as follows, replacing `res_id` with the ID of the file above.

```
XmlResourceParser resourceParser = activity.getResources().getXml(R.xml.res_id);
AttributeSet attrs = Xml.asAttributeSet(resourceParser);

CustomView view = new CustomView(activity, attrs);
```

Comment: I created attrs.xml file with tag declare-styleable , but getXml function does not work with styleable .

Comment: So, only solution that I found, that probably is not good is to set attributes in code and create the view with null parameter in constructor. If I don't pass AttributeSet in constructor I got error: Problem loading widget

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise it wouldn't work with declare-styleable. Is the decalre-styleable really necessary? If you *have* to do it with code, then it's fine to set the attributes via code the way you said. Try just passing the context/activity to the constructor, i.e. don't have a second argument at all. CustomView view = new CustomView(activity).

Comment: i try it witout attributeset but it doesnt work it says problem loading widget

Comment: There could be any number of things wrong. You'll need to look at the stacktrace in logcat to see what is causing the error.